ZFS "cannot open" and "too many errors"
I got an alert this morning that one of my arrays was having a problem. I can't seem to get past it. I'm not sure how to proceed.
admin@ICSSAN1:~$ zpool status -v
  pool: SAS_Array
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.  There are insufficient replicas for the pool to
        continue functioning.
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source.  Manually marking the device
        repaired using 'zpool clear' may allow some data to be recovered.
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        SAS_Array                  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          mirror-0                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            c4t5000C50058EFEB57d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c4t5000C500628BA8ABd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            c4t5000C500628BA727d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c4t5000C500628BB013d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-2                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            c4t5000C5005D78F05Bd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c4t5000C500628BB4D7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-3                 UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
            c4t5000C500626EFAFBd0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0  FAULTED      0     0     0  too many errors

  pool: syspool
 state: ONLINE
 scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h32m with 0 errors on Sun Jun  2 03:32:11 2024
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        syspool     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0d1s0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
admin@ICSSAN1:~$ zpool clear SAS_Array c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0
cannot clear errors for c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0: permission denied
admin@ICSSAN1:~$ su
Password:
root@ICSSAN1:/export/home/admin# zpool clear SAS_Array c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0
cannot clear errors for c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0: one or more devices is currently unavailable
root@ICSSAN1:/export/home/admin# zpool clear SAS_Array c4t5000C500626EFAFBd0
cannot clear errors for c4t5000C500626EFAFBd0: one or more devices is currently unavailable

System information
SunOS ICSSAN1 5.11 NexentaOS_134f i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0 FAULTED 1 3 0 too many errors

That was the report on the "too many errors disk" just before the "cannot open" one failed, so it was not an excessive failure.
Can I just swap the "cannot open" disk and force it back online?
It looks like my hotspare wasn't correctly added to the volume, so it didn't activate when it was supposed to. Now that the volume is unavailable, it won't add it in.

Quick question: What Nexenta support has to say?

Chances are that this system is wayyy out of support and that Nexenta won't be helpful.

@ewwhite Correct, it's an old Nextena that if enterprise, would be out of support. It's the community version.

See if you can check the health of the physical drives.
This is unfortunate because you lost both sides of a mirrored pair. However, this is potentially recoverable, depending on the nature of the errors encountered on the "FAULTED" disk.
The repair and troubleshooting steps are specific to your environment and iterative. This may not work well in the Q&A format.
This is also labeled as Nexenta. Did you receive an error about the "UNAVAIL" disk at any point? ZFS can be very resilient, but if there was a missed alert about the device failure, there was additional exposure and risk.

Edit:

Do you have backups? (this helps gauge what techniques can be used)
Do you have physical access to the server? (you may want to get a visual)
How important is the data?
Can you run a physical power-off (remove system power and let drives spin down), then power on?

Depending on the answers, I'd power cycle to see if you can get the  c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0 disk to come online. Nexenta may have ejected or kicked that disk out of the pool prematurely or in response to a different set of errors.
If you can get that disk online, it may be possible to restore the pool to good health with minimal damage/data loss.
--
Edit:
Try to bring the faulted device online directly.
zpool online SAS_Array c4t5000C50062F4D23Fd0

Check the result...
zpool clear SAS_Array


"This may not work well in the Q&A format." Are there more appropriate formats for resolving this issue?
"health of the physical drives." The one that's listed as "cannot open" doesn't show up in the HBA controller's BIOS. What additional resources should I be looking at for diagnosing the physical health? smartctl doesn't seem to exist on my platform.
"Did you receive an error about the "UNAVAIL" disk at any point?" No alert was received about the "UNAVAIL" disk, only the "FAULTED" disk.

Good questions. I'm a ZFS engineer and specialize in this type of repair, but there are too many variables to discover. I'll add more to my answer.

"Do you have backups?" No.
"Do you have physical access to the server?" Yes. What I assume to be the UNAVAIL disk is blinking at a constant rate while the rest of the array blinks in unison (and rarely at that).
"How important is the data?" It's not life or death, but it isn't trivial either. I am quite incentivized to recover with minimal data loss.
"Can you run a physical power-off..." I did to no effect. I powered down and swapped the UNAVAIL and FAULTED disks with each other's slot to diagnose if it was a slot issue. No difference, other than the disk IDs swapped spots.

It looks like my hotspare wasn't correctly added to the volume, so it didn't activate when it was supposed to. Now that the volume is unavailable, it won't add it in.

How recently was this server configured? Nexenta hasn't been a major factor in ZFS storage for a long time.

@MHammett See my edited post.

The output of the commands you wanted me to run was too long for here, so I put it in the Reddit thread that you found.
It's...  it's been a while. Oddly enough, I was looking to move everything over to Proxmox... put the new servers into my shopping cart and everything.

Thanks @MHammett. This is fixable and likely recoverable, but it’s a deeper effort involving a Linux ZFS installation, additional tools, and is well beyond what we can describe here.  Please contact if you need an estimate/pricing.
